# Amortized Analysis

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

I came across this problem while studying which asks to consider a data structure where a sequence of n operations are performed. If the kth operation has a cost of k if it is a perfect square and a cost of 1 otherwise, what is total cost of the operations and what is the amortized cost of each operation.

I am having a bit of difficulty coming up with a summation formula that provides the definition of a perfect square where I can see what the sum yields. Any thoughts/advice?

Comment: Your question is not clear at the moment. Try to add some example to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of i^2 from 1 to n can be calculated as `n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`. I found it in a math book, can't find a simple formula online. But check out http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sum.html, formula (6).

To calculate this sum, let `n` be the square root of `k`, rounded down. The formula is proportional to `n^3` which is `sqrt(k)^3 = k^(3/2)`. This gives an amortized time of `O(k^(3/2))`.

Comment: Why is the formula with the square root of k proportional to n^3?

Comment: n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = (2n^3+2n^2+n^2+n)/6, the largest term is 2n^3/6 which is proportional to n^3

Comment: So amortized cost for each operation using would be just O(k)